# Using swift URLComponents to extract param value from url

Tags: ios, swift, core-foundation, urlcomponents

I've tried the following code in order to extract param value out of an existing url address

```
func getQueryStringParameter(url: String, param: String) -> String? {
    guard let urlItems = URLComponents(string: url) else { return nil }
    return urlItems.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == param })?.value
}
```

I called this method with the following input :

```
url = myprefix:un%3Dtest%26add=%3D1%26token%3Dbbbbbbbb
param = token
```

and I'd expect that the function to return token's value 'bbbbbbbb'

however, although the url is being parsed properly (here's printout from the debugger), the queryItems returns `nil`

```
po URLComponents(string: "myprefix:un%3Dtest%26add=%3D1%26token%3Dbbbbbbbb")
▿ Optional<URLComponents>
  ▿ some : myprefix:un%3Dtest%26add=%3D1%26token%3Dbbbbbbbb
    - scheme : "myprefix"
    - path : "un=test&add==1&token=bbbbbbbb"
```

How can I modify the function so that queryItems will be valid and I may extract the values out of `path` properly ?

EDIT: after changing the ':' to '?' it looks like the query still isn't parsed properly because the `UTF-8` formatting of the url, is there any way to convert it to the ascii representation automatically?

ascii :

```
(lldb) po URLComponents(string: "myprefix?un=test&add=1&token=bbbbbbbb")?.queryItems
▿ Optional<Array<URLQueryItem>>
  ▿ some : 3 elements
    ▿ 0 : un=test
      - name : "un"
      ▿ value : Optional<String>
        - some : "test"
    ▿ 1 : add=1
      - name : "add"
      ▿ value : Optional<String>
        - some : "1"
    ▿ 2 : token=bbbbbbbb
      - name : "token"
      ▿ value : Optional<String>
        - some : "bbbbbbbb"
```

UTF-8 :

```
(lldb) po URLComponents(string: "myprefix?un%3Dtest%26add=%3D1%26token%3Dbbbbbbbb")?.queryItems?.first
▿ Optional<URLQueryItem>
  ▿ some : un=test&add==1&token=bbbbbbbb
    - name : "un=test&add"
    ▿ value : Optional<String>
      - some : "=1&token=bbbbbbbb"
```

thanks

Comment: I would have expected a `?` to precede the query, I guess that's why it's seeing it as the `path` and not the query items... So you might fake it. If queryItems.isEmpty, construct an new URL with `http://something.com/thisone?pathYouGotFromURLComponents` to have valid ones?

Comment: @Larme, Hi I've changed the `:` to `?` but i still need to change the UTF-8 to ascii representation... do you know how to convert it automatically beforehand ?

Comment: It's an encoding UTF8/ASCII issue? I would have said that why is your query percent escaped? That's strange, no? In you last sample, on "=" isn't percent espcaped.

Comment: Your url seems to be gibberish. It seems to be partially url encoded and is missing the ? for a query string in both une coded and encoded form

Comment: @Larme, basically i'm using the framework ASWebAuthenticationSession in order to get the url from the browser. however, it must have the ":" in ascii to get the callback working, and the rest of the address is indeed UTF-8. So perhaps do you know a way to convert all utf-8 to ascii in a string ?